# Building Meteor app returns Error: EPERM, symlink

Tags: javascript, meteor, build, npm

I'm attempting to build a Meteor application in an offline environment, with local web servers but no access to the outside Internet.

On running `meteor build ./output` I get the following:

> ...AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\templating\1.1.9\plugin.compileTemplatesBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\promise\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:116
>
> throw error;
>
> Error: EPERM, symlink '..\babylon\bin\babylon.js'

This application runs fine in localhost, doesn't seem to have any issues, but on attempting to `build` or `bundle` the app I run into these issues.

Additional (perhaps useful) info:

`meteor build ./output --verbose` returns the following (unnecessary packages omitted)

> Local package version is up-to-date: templating@1.1.9
>
> Local package version is up-to-date: templating-tools@1.0.4

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run meteor as an administrator, then it can create the symlinks.

Comment: this should be a comment